# How to debug this code for splitting an array by space?

Tags: c++

I need to write a program that get a sentence and split its words by a delimiter(space);so I've wrote the code below but it doesn't seem to be working properly.
any idea's how to debug this code?
thanks in advance for your help.
here's what I come up with so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int BUFFER_SIZE=255;


int main()
{       
       char* buffer;
       buffer=new char[255];
       cout<<"enter a statement:"<<endl;
    cin.getline(buffer,BUFFER_SIZE);
    int q=0, numofwords=1;
    while(buffer[q] != '\0'){
        if(buffer[q]==' ') numofwords ++;
        q ++;
    }
    char** wordsArray;
    wordsArray= new char* [numofwords];  

    int lenofeachword=0, num=0;
    int* sizeofwords=new int [numofwords];
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
        if(buffer[i]==' ')
        {
            sizeofwords[num]=lenofeachword;
            wordsArray[num]=new char[lenofeachword];
            num++; 
        }else{
        lenofeachword++;
        }



    }
    sizeofwords[num]=lenofeachword;  
    wordsArray[num]=new char[lenofeachword]; 
    int k=0;
    for(int i=0; i<numofwords;i++){

        for(int j=0;j<sizeofwords[i];j++)
        {
            wordsArray[i][j]=buffer[k];
            k++;

        }
        k++;
    }

   for(int i=0; i<numofwords;i++){

            for(int j=0;j<sizeofwords[i];j++)
            {
                cout<<wordsArray[i][j];

            }
        cout<<endl;

        }
 }
```

Comment: In C++ you should be using `std::string` and `std::vector` for dynamically allocated storage. Using `new` and `delete` is considered very bad style as it's prone to memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int size, j;
    char s[1005];
    gets(s);
    scanf("%d", &size);
    j=0;
    for(int i=size; i<strlen(s); i+=size) {
        for(; j<i; j++) {
            printf("%c", s[j]);
        }
        printf(" ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1 for using C library where type-safe C++ functionality exists.

Comment: @JanHudec you think so. then, can you pls show us how to read whole sentence "type-safe"-ly in C++

Comment: Use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) for getting the line from `std::istream` (that is _different_ from `std::istream::getline`, unfortunately) and then either again `std::getline` from `std::stringstream` or iterate over the `std::string`, looking for spaces with it's `find` method.

Comment: @JanHudec thanx. but thats so long and complexive to me. i just prefer c-style and gets(), though i know its depreciated. its less line and less code

Comment: It is neither longer nor more complex and you don't get a buffer overrun.

Comment: By the way, your code does nothing remotely similar to the one in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign zero to `lenofeachword` after you deretmine lenght of a word. And if `int main()`, you should return an int value.